# How do you flatten a Sequence of Sequences in Ceylon?

Tags: sequence, ceylon

Given a type that is a Sequence of Sequences, how do I convert it to a single, flattened Sequence type? Consider the following Ceylon code:

```
Integer[] range(Integer max) {
    return [ for (idx in 1..max) idx ];
}

Integer[] prod(Integer max, Integer occurrences) {
    Integer[][] nestedSequence = [for (occurrence in 1..occurrences) range(max)];
    return // ??? something to produce a flattened sequence 
}

assert (prod(2, 2) == [1, 2, 1, 2]);
```

I'm experimenting with Ceylon for the first time and fumbling my way through the tutorials and API documentation. The [unzip method](http://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.0.0/module-doc/index.html#unzip) looks somewhat close to what I need, but not exactly.

Comment: Should the last line of code be `assert (prod(2, 2) == [1, 2, 1, 2]);`?

Comment: @gdejohn - fixed. I had been stripping the code down for posting purposes and re-named the methods, but forgot to change the `assert`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variadic function `concatenate()` concatenates iterables, producing a sequence:

```
Integer[] prod(Integer max, Integer occurrences) {
    Integer[][] nestedSequence = [ for (occurrence in 1..occurrences) range(max) ];
    return concatenate(*nestedSequence);
}
```

This can be rewritten less verbosely like this:

```
Integer[] prod(Integer max, Integer occurrences)
        => concatenate(for (occurrence in 1..occurrences) range(max));
```

But I don't like this implementation because it does lots of eager instantiation of sequences. I would *much* prefer this implementation, which only does one sequence instantiation:

```
Integer[] prod4(Integer max, Integer occurrences)
        => [ for (occurrence in 1..occurrences) for (x in range(max)) x ];
```

FYI, in Ceylon 1.1, the `expand()` function has been added which is lazier than `concatenate()`.

HTH, good luck!

Comment: @BDKosher's `range()` unnecessarily wraps a range in a sequence, so it can be dropped to further simplify that last implementation: `[for (occurrence in 1..occurrences) for (x in 1..max) x]`

Comment: To be clear, `concatenate()` is not really meant to be used like this.  It's really meant for the case where you have a fixed list of iterables, e.g. `concatenate(xs,ys,zs)`. The new function `expand()` is intended for the mentioned usecase.

Comment: This helps. I had totally failed to notice the spread operator until now. @gdejohn, if I'm following you correctly, even if there are multiple `for`s within square braces, it's one Sequence instantiation per pair of square braces?

Comment: @BDKosher `[for (occurrence in 1..occurrences) for (x in 1..max) x]` does result in a single sequence. Multiple comprehensions inside a sequence instantiation just act as if they're nested.

Answer (score 1):

Your `range` function isn't useful here because it unnecessarily creates a sequence around a range. You just need to iterate from `1` to `max`, and you can do that directly with the range created by `1..max`. So, replacing `range(max)` with `1..max`, you can define `prod` like this:

```
Integer[] prod(Integer max, Integer occurrences)
        => (1..max).repeat(occurrences);
```

---

To answer your question, in the absence of `concatenate` and `expand` as mentioned in [Gavin's answer](/a/20308666/464306), you can produce a flattened sequence from `nestedSequence` using `Iterable.fold()` like this:

```
nestedSequence.fold({}, ({Integer*} f, Integer[] r) => f.chain(r)).sequence;
```

Equivalently,

```
Element[] flattened<Element>(Element[][] nestedSequence) {
    variable {Element*} flattened = {}; // same as f above
    for (Element[] range in nestedSequence) { // range is same as r above
        flattened = flattened.chain(range);
    }
    return flattened.sequence;
}
```

But I prefer Gavin's last implementation, using comprehensions. Strikes me as more idiomatic Ceylon compared to `fold`.